# MAMP mssql_connect( ) returning login failed

Tags: php, sql-server, authentication, mamp

I have been trying to access an MSSQL Database in a server inside my network, it seems to be able to find the database, but does not accept the authentication.

I get the following error:

**"mssql_connect(): message: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."**

I have been trying to solve this for a few days now, with no success...

I tried adding the MAMP server into the hosts file in the windows machine, I know the account I am using works since I am able to access the database with those credentials while logging in through a Database Client (AquaData Studio) and of course while logging in locally via the SQL Server Management Studio.

I read that by default mssql_connect uses Windows Authentication (mssql.secure.connection Off in the php.ini) That is the authentication method I am using under the AquaData Studio client.

I have the freeTDS libary installed under the mssql as well...

Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

I believe it should be working since It finds the server, but fails on the authentication... Please help!

Comment: MAMP is for Apple? Do you mean WAMP?

Comment: I am trying to connect to a Windows Server MSSQL Database host with a Mac using MAMP. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Dou you have Trusted_Connection=**true** in the connection string?

Comment: I have not tried that... It may be a dumb question, but ... I assume the use of mssql_connect($server,$usr,$pwd); is not the way to connect to it? or how could I declare that attribute under the mssql_connect command? I apologize, but this is the very first time I find this and I am 100% self taught